# How precise should I encode a Unix Time?

Tags: unix-timestamp

I came across this because I am working with time across multiple platforms and seems like they all differ a little bit from each other in how unix time is implemented and/or handled in their system. Thus the question.

Quoting [Wikipedia page on Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> Unix has no tradition of directly representing non-integer Unix time numbers as binary fractions. Instead, times with sub-second precision are represented using composite data types that consist of two integers, the first being a time_t (the integral part of the Unix time), and the second being the fractional part of the time number in millionths (in struct timeval) or billionths (in struct timespec). These structures provide a decimal-based fixed-point data format, which is useful for some applications, and trivial to convert for others.

Which seems to be the implemention in Go (UnixNano). However, in practice, there are many languages/platforms which use milliseconds (Java?) and also some platforms uses Float (to try to maintain some precision) and others mostly uses Int.

---

So if I'm implementing a transport format and I only have exactly 64 bits available to store a time value and no more, my question is two-fold:

- Should I encode it as an integer or a floating-point value? And
- Should I use seconds, milliseconds or nanosecond precision?

The main goal being to try to be as accurate as possible across as many languages and platforms as possible (without resorting to custom code in every single platform, of course).

---

p.s. I know this is a little subjective but I believe it's still possible to make a good, objective answer. Feel free to close if that's not the case.

Comment: One thing to consider is that time_t values for now are quite large, requiring about 30 bits. So since a doube has 53 bits of ptecision there are not enough bits in a double to store a time_t + nanoseconds. (There are enough for microseconds). You could get round this for a while by defining your own epoch (ie subtracting a great big number from the number of seconds) but since there are ~ 32M seconds in a year, you;d soon run out of room in a double if you want to keep nanosecond accuracy,

Comment: It all depends on your requirements. How large a time range you must support and the precision required by the programs using your transport format. No, I don’t see how a more objective answer than this could be supplied based on the information you have provided.

Comment: The maximum portability is the requirement. `as accurate as possible across as my languages and platforms as possible`

Comment: I understand you want a generic answer, but that will lack in some way.  It would be good for us what is the application (in any language, platform).  As for precission I would personally go for `milliseconds` that is the.  Usually if you need to go below it you need some special equipment or hw, etc.

Comment: What are you doing with this data, are you consuming it, mutating, or adding it?

Comment: The application is a protocol definition. It's for transfer of timestamp value from one platform to another. I'm defining a storage/communication protocol that will be used across several platforms. For reasons I have no control over, it is limited to 64bits. And once it is live, I will not be able to change it, ever, thus the question.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what the required precision of the time value is, and its maximal range.

When storing nanoseconds in an unsigned 64bit integer, the range is about 584 years (2^64 ns), so precise and long enough for any practical application already.

Using a floating point format has the advantage that both very small and very large values can be stored, with higher absolute precision for smaller values. But with 64bit it this probably not a problem anyways.

---

If the time value is an absolute point in time instead of duration, the transform format would also need to define what date/time the value 0 stands for. (i.e. the Epoch)

Getting the current time on a UNIX-like system can be done using `gettimeofday()`,  for example, which returns a struct with a seconds and microseconds value. This can then be converted into a single 64bit integer giving a value in microseconds. The Epoch for UNIX time is 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UT. (The `clock()` function does not measure real time, but instead the duration of time that the processor was active.)

When a time value for the same transport format is generated on another platform (for example Windows with `GetSystemTime()`, it would need to be converted to the same unit and epoch.

---

So the following things would need to be fixed for a transport protocol:

- The unit of the time value (ms, us, ...), depending on required precision and range
- If the time is a time point and not a duration, the Epoch (date and time of value 0)
- Whether it is stored in an integer (unsigned or signed, if it is a duration that can be negative), or as a floating point
- The endianess of the 64bit value
- If floating point is used, the format of the floating point value (normally IEEE 754)

Because different platforms have different APIs to get the current time, probably it would always need some code to properly convert the time value, but this is trivial.

Comment: "_with higher absolute precision for smaller values_" But this breaks time invariance of the program: the farther in time from the Epoch, the worse the precision. Doesn't sound good. And the significand length reduces from 64 bits (or 63 for signed time values) to 53 in IEEE754 `double`, just to store the useless exponent.

Comment: Using floating point type might be useful for *durations* instead of absolute *time points*. But with 64bit it is probably better to use an integer anyways.

Comment: To appeal to authority, C++'s [`std::chrono::nanoseconds`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) is indeed stored in a signed integer type of at least 64 bits.  (Signed being necessary since it represents a duration.)

Comment: The point about exponent not being very useful is a good one  Didn't think about that before.

Comment: @IceGlasses In what universe can you have a negative duration?

Comment: Even with a fixed epoch zero, you need to define how the clock seconds and timestamps deal with UTC leap seconds. About 30 leap secs since 1972, they are not applied on a schedule you need a lookup table. Some systems use straight atomic time(TAI) in place of UTC, so they are approx 30 secs different but can be converted to UTC with a lookup table. New leap secs are generally announced several months in advance by hpiers.obspm.fr UTC and TAI differ by exact integer secs. Prior to 1972 UTC had no leap secs and so is permanently 10s misaligned with solar noon. GPSS time has no leap secs.

Comment: @MaxPower The STL universe   Which is to say, not a negative "duration", but a negative `std::chrono::duration`, which is the type you get when you add or subtract times.  So if you do [earlier time] - [later time] you end up with a negative duration.

Comment: Ah, yes. Personally, I call subtracting a later time from earlier a logic error and semantically the result is no longer a duration but a difference. But then to some extent the STD tries to be everything to everybody, so accommodates strange use cases where possible.

Answer (score 4):

For maximum portability and accuracy, you should probably go with a type specified by POSIX. That way, the code will be portable across all Unixes and other operating systems conforming to POSIX.

I suggest that you use `clock_t` and the `clock()` function for time. This has a variety of uses, including measuring time and distance between one point in a program and another. Just make sure to cast the result to a `double` and divide by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` afterwards to convert that time into a human-readable format.

So, to answer your question:

1. Use both an integer and a floating-point value
2. Unsure precision (the number of clock cycles between calls) but accurate enough for all non-critical applications and some more important ones

Comment: `clock()` does not measure real time, but only the time the processor has been busy between two points. To get real (wall) time, `gettimeofday()` or `clock_gettime()` should be used. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock

Comment: @tmlen I was under the assumption that he was talking about the `time` command.

Comment: The posix standard [my info may be out of date] handles leap seconds in a sloppy way by repeating a second and that leads to ambiguous timestamps, such that one timestamp can actually be either of two points in time.